# Renaming Visual Studio installation on Windows

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

I've had Visual Studio Community 2019 installed, and then I installed VS Enterprise 2019. Now everywhere in Windows (i.e. Start menu, Settings>Apps list), it shows up as "Visual Studio 2019 (2)", also "Blend for Visual Studio 2019 (2)", even though I've uninstalled VS Community 2019, and it's bugging me a bit. How can I change that without reinstalling?

Answer (score 2):

If the shortcut name is the problem, here is how to rename an entry in the Windows 10
Start menu:

- Right-click on the Start menu items that you want to rename
- Click on *More > Open file location*
- Right-click on the shortcut of the item and select *Rename*
- Type the new name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.